# How to Save HasMany Associations Data in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: php, save, cakephp-3.0

> I've problem when saving data with hasMany association. There are two
>   tables like bellow. Now When I save it , it is saving data only
>   services table, but it is not saving to service_times table.  Also I
>   have given here template and controller code. Can any one suggest me,
>   how can I solve this issue.

```
1) services table: 
id | id   | ... 
1  | name | ...

2) service_times table
id | id   | ... 
1  | service_id | ...
2  | star_time | (type= time)
3  | end_time | (type= time)
```

**TEMPLATE FORM:**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($service) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Service') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('ServiceTimes.start_time');
            echo $this->Form->input('ServiceTimes.end_time');
            echo $this->Form->input('description');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**SERVICE CONTROLLER**

```
public function add(){
      $service = $this->Services->newEntity($this->request->data, [
                'associated' => ['ServiceTimes']
            ]);

            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                if ($this->Services->save($service, ['associated' => ['ServiceTimes']])) {
                    pr($this->request->data);exit;
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The service has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                } else {
                    $this->Flash->error(__('The service could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
                }
            }
        //}

        $this->set(compact('service'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['service']);
        $this->viewBuilder()->theme('ThemeAdmin');
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest having a look at the docs to get a grasp on how associated data is ment to be structured in order to be saved properly. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data** | **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations**

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that a smart solution would be to create a different entity for service_times table and include a small form for that table inside this one where you save only those two attributes. That should solve the "save" part of the problem.

Comment: That sounds more of a workaround for not understanding how saving associations work... wouldn't recommend doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solve it by following way:

**my CTP file like**

```
<?= $this->Form->create($service) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Service') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('serviceTimes.start_time');
            echo $this->Form->input('serviceTimes.end_time');
            echo $this->Form->input('description');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**Controller function**

```
public function add()
    {
        $service = $this->Services->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $service = $this->Services->patchEntity($service, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Services->save($service)) {
               // Last inserted service id
                $service_id = $service->id;
                $serviceTime = $this->Services->ServiceTimes->newEntity();
                $serviceTime->service_id = $service_id;
                $serviceTime->start_time = $this->request->data['serviceTimes']['start_time'];
                $serviceTime->end_time = $this->request->data['serviceTimes']['end_time'];
                if ($this->Services->ServiceTimes->save($serviceTime)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('The service has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                }
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The service could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }

        $this->set(compact('service'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['service']);
        $this->viewBuilder()->theme('ThemeAdmin');
    }
```